# Is there a keyboard shortcut to minimize the Prosperworks CRM sidebar in Gmail?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gmail, google-chrome-extensions, crm

In Gmail, the Prosperworks Chrome Extension takes up a lot of space on the side. It auto-expands upon a new pageload which is really annoying when I don't want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "custom search engine" to easily minimize the sidebar with a keyboard shortcut.

1. go here: chrome://settings/searchEngines
2. scroll to "Other Search Engines", and click "ADD"
3. - Name it whatever you want. Search engines are listed alphabetically so I named mine "zzz Minimize Prosperworks" to make it easy to find.
   - Keyword: `i`. This is the keyboard shortcut you'll use to shut the Prosperworks sidebar. I use "i" because it's close to resting hand position.
   - URL with %s in place of query: `javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('PWExtensionFrame_toggleIcon')[0].click();`
4. Now, when you want to minimize the Prosperworks sidebar, you:

   1. `⌘ + L` to select the URL bar,
   2. `i` to invoke the custom search bar,
   3. `enter` to execute it.